# Use primary Id as idempotency token on API

Tags: api, security, idempotent

i want to know if using  primary  id: 1;2;3;... can be used as idempotency toekn on API  instead of using long string  UUID.
as id is unique  i think  it can be
is there any risk?

Comment: Ids can be easily guessed

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend always using random idompotency tokens rather than reusing other values you have (like primary keys or sequential numbers).

It makes replaying sequences of commands during a debug session difficult if the IDs used for idempotency might overlap due to test data being reset, or other ways that you want to send the same test data in a request twice in a short period of time and not have the second request ignored.

An attacker may also be able to do a denial of service on your use of the API is they know enough to cause the web service to think that an idempotency token has already been used in a window. If you don't use a random token then you should consider the situations in which someone could disrupt your use of the service by sending their own requests with tokens that you will use (either guessed or just because they aren't generating random tokens themselves). Using either predictable or 'common' tokens in this situation will cause a problem. If the web service does not record tokens for attempts to call the web service without a valid authentication, then this is less of (or not) an issue.